# FileSystemWatcher Error Event not raised if watched folder is deleted - but only if watched folder has files within

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

I am using the FileSystemWatcher for its usual purpose. However I was testing the use of it's error event when I found a peculiar issue.

If I set the FSW to watch a given **EMPTY** folder and set it running, if I delete the folder the FSW raises its error event with an "Access Denied" message in the exception.

If I recreate the folder and put a single file in side say text file then run up my test app again if I then delete the folder this time the error event is not raised.

This is bemusing to me. Does anyone know why this would be the case.  I'm getting that feeling that I'm doing something silly wrong here.

so summary of problem:

- Delete Empty watched folder: FSW Error event raised.
- Delete Non-Empty watched folder: FSW Error event NOT raised.

Here is the code for the test console app.

```
class Program
{
    static WatcherTests tests;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        InitialiseWatcher();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void InitialiseWatcher()
    {
        tests = new WatcherTests();
        tests.InitialiseWatcher();
    }
}

class WatcherTests
{
    FileSystemWatcher _watcher;

    internal void InitialiseWatcher()
    {
        _watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
        _watcher.Changed += OnWatcher_Changed;
        _watcher.Created += OnWatcher_Created;
        _watcher.Deleted += OnWatcher_Deleted;
        _watcher.Error += OnWatcher_Error;
        _watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = false;
        _watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
        _watcher.Path = @"c:\temp\testwatcher";
        _watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }

    private void OnWatcher_Error(object sender, ErrorEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Watcher_Error {e.GetException().Message}");
    }

    private void OnWatcher_Deleted(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Watcher_Deleted {e.Name}");
    }

    private void OnWatcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Watcher_Created {e.Name}");
    }

    private void OnWatcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Watcher_Changed {e.Name}");
    }
}
```

Comment: I just did exactly what you described and got 2 events - the file deleted event and then the error event.  (I tried with recycling - no events.  Tried again without recycling - shift+delete - and got both events again).

Comment: Yeah I can confirm that behaviour, hmm. So you think there is an issue with the FSW with this regard?

Comment: I think it's more likely that there's something different about our environments that is causing it to act differently.  It's certainly odd.

Comment: I'm researching this now and it might be expected behaviour as the file going to the recycle bin is not actually deleted - still not sure why that would cause the error event not to be raised, since the folder is not accessible anymore.

Comment: The folder isn't deleted either though - if you restore it and then do a hard delete it raises the error event.  I'm not sure how the FSW works internally, whether it hooks Windows internal events, or simply polls for changes regularly.  If it's the former then I'm guessing that deleting to the recycle bin simply doesn't publish a deleted event.

Comment: Yeah I know, but its still inaccessible whilst in the recyclable state.

Comment: Apparently moving to the recycle bin should trigger a renamed event, but I couldn't get that to work.  I'm starting to remember why I only ever used the FSW once, a long, long time ago.

Comment: Ive been trying this too, cant get it to raise any event on recycling..

Comment: Not so sure this adds up, if you want an event for the *folder* to be deleted then you'd have to watch its parent directory.  Afaik FSW opens a handle on the directory with delete sharing enabled.  Which does not block a delete, the file system directory entry for the directory won't disappear until that handle is closed.  Trying to do anything at all with the delete-pending directory will trip an access denied error, make sure that isn't the one you see.

Comment: The FSW watches the content of a directory, not the directory itself. You can rename it, and you'll still receive notifications (the handle won't change), but the name change will not be notified. If you send it to the Recycle Bin, it's a rename. If you delete the Dir from the RB, you'll get the notification if that Dir contains some files or other directories (and you're watching the subdiretories). You should verify in a delete/rename event if the Dir still contains some elements. If it's not, start a polling that checks if the Dir is still there. If it's not, stop the FSW and notify/log.

Comment: Another way, as Hans mentioned, is to start a secondary FSW that watches only the Directory modifications of the Parent Directory, using as a filter, the name of the watched directory + `"*"`. Then, you'll also receive notifications when the watched directory is renamed/modified etc.

Comment: Thanks, the reason I started to query the error event was due to an accidental deletion of the folder I was watching, and I wanted to build protection against that in the future.  I had hoped that when the watched folder was deleted I would get a FSW error event which I could act on - which you do if the folder is empty.  But now I know I need a secondary system to keep checking that the folder exists and is accessible.